# mysql rank - row number where field is equal to X

Tags: mysql

This is my mysql DB:
**id, auth, name, points**

and what I want to get is to create a rank. So sort all the records by points, and get the number of the row where the **auth** field is equal to '**1**'

I were looking for this in stockoverflow archive, in google etc. However, I havn't find what I were looking for. I were trying to do it myself, but none of them didn't work for me.

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE auth = 1`?

Comment: nothing is wrong with it, however there wasn't rank field, and I wanted to do it automatically via query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT a.iterator, a.id, a.name, a.points
FROM (    
    SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS iterator, id, name, points, auth
    FROM table, (SELECT @rank:=0) tmp
    ORDER BY points DESC) a
WHERE a.auth = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the record with rank for the record with auth = 1:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT id, auth, name, points, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM (
    SELECT id, auth, name, points
    FROM yourTable
    ORDER BY points DESC
    ) a
  JOIN (
    SELECT @rownum := 0
    ) r
  ) b
WHERE b.auth = 1;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b12b/2)</kbd>

Comment: Note the order by inside the derived table will not assure that the results will be order to the outsider select statement. Check out the other solution in which the variable is incremented in the same statement as the order by